# How can I escape a command passed to bash via bash -c?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, escaping

I would like to run the following command via `docker -c`:

```
for line in `docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v CONTAINER`; do docker ps | grep $line | awk '{printf $NF" "}' && echo $(( `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$line*/memory.usage_in_bytes` / 1024 / 1024 ))MB ; done
```

How do I have to escape the command when passing it via `-c`? What symbols do I have to escape?

I tried various versions, including this one, which gives me the error `unexpected EOF while looking for matching "`

```
bash -c 'for line in \`docker ps | awk \'{print $1}\' | grep -v CONTAINER\`\; do docker ps | grep $line | awk \'{printf $NF\\" \\"}\' && echo $(( \`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$line*/memory.usage_in_bytes\` / 1024 / 1024 ))MB \; done
```

Sidenote: The command gives you the memory consumption for each docker container.

Comment: Using $() instead of backticks may help in the first instance.

Comment: `bash -c 'for line in $(docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v CONTAINER); do docker ps | grep $line | awk '{printf $NF\" \"}' && echo $(( $(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$line*/memory.usage_in_bytes) / 1024 / 1024 ))MB ; done'` gives me an unmatched `)`

Comment: This seems complex enough that I'd write it into a script file.  (It can also be simplified significantly; for example, `docker ps -q` will print out all of the running container IDs without any decoration.)

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: `for line in $(awk cmd); do ... awk ...` is an anti-apttern

Comment: why are these anti-patterns? What is wrong with them?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to divide the number of bytes.
In order to do arithmetic calculations you need to use `expr`.
Try this:

```
for line in `docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v CONTAINER`; do docker ps | grep $line | awk '{printf $NF" "}' && echo $(expr $( cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$line*/memory.usage_in_bytes) / 1024 / 1024 )MB ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `expr` does make it a lot easier.

Comment: bash can do arithmetic. No need to call out to expr

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
bash -c 'for line in $(docker ps | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | grep -v CONTAINER); do docker ps | grep $line | awk '"'"'{printf $NF" "}'"'"' && echo $(( $(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$line*/memory.usage_in_bytes) / 1024 / 1024 ))MB ; done'
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Post this as a separate question, or update the question, rather than embedding a second question in an answer.

Comment: Basically, you cannot put single quotes in a single quoted string. So you have to close the single quoted string and concatenate a literal single quote.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, it's a good use case for Bash printf `%q` specifier. Save a line to a
file, say /tmp/DOCKER-COMMAND and then format it with `printf %q`:

```
$ printf "%q\n" "$(< /tmp/DOCKER-COMMAND)"
for\ line\ in\ \`docker\ ps\ \|\ awk\ \'\{print\ \$1\}\'\ \|\ grep\ -v\ CONTAINER\`\;\ do\ docker\ ps\ \|\ grep\ \$line\ \|\ awk\ \'\{printf\ \$NF\"\ \"\}\'\ \&\&\ echo\ \$\(\(\ \`cat\ /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/\$line\*/memory.usage_in_bytes\`\ /\ 1024\ /\ 1024\ \)\)MB\ \;\ done
```

You can copy the output line and paste it literally to `bash -c`:

```
$ bash -c for\ line\ in\ \`docker\ ps\ \|\ awk\ \'\{print\ \$1\}\'\ \|\ grep\ -v\ CONTAINER\`\;\ do\ docker\ ps\ \|\ grep\ \$line\ \|\ awk\ \'\{printf\ \$NF\"\ \"\}\'\ \&\&\ echo\ \$\(\(\ \`cat\ /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/\$line\*/memory.usage_in_bytes\`\ /\ 1024\ /\ 1024\ \)\)MB\ \;\ done
fervent_gates 2MB
youthful_wozniak 3MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to fit in a single line? Using a quoted heredoc gets you out of most quoting trouble:

```sh
bash <<'END_BASH'
    docker ps | {
        read header
        while read -ra fields; do 
            mem=$(< /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/"${fields[0]}"*/memory.usage_in_bytes)
            printf "%s %dMB\n" "${fields[-1]}" $((mem / 1024 / 1024))
        done
    }
END_BASH
```